# Eclipse Update Maven Project > error SAXParserFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm on Eclipse 2020-06 and when I try to performe the "Update Maven Project" I get the error:

*An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
org.eclipse.core.internal.content.Activator.getFactory()Ljavax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory;*

Looking following links the problem seems related to a class removed in the eclipse core that was used from some plug-in. Now it should be resolved... but I still didn't get how to solve it.

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=565222
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564634
- https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1104205/

This is the error stacktrace:

*java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.core.internal.content.Activator.getFactory()Ljavax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory;
at org.fusesource.ide.foundation.core.xml.namespace.FindNamespaceHandlerSupport.parseContents(FindNamespaceHandlerSupport.java:67)
at org.fusesource.ide.foundation.core.xml.namespace.NamespaceXmlContentDescriberSupport.fillContentProperties(NamespaceXmlContentDescriberSupport.java:106)
at org.fusesource.ide.foundation.core.xml.namespace.NamespaceXmlContentDescriberSupport.checkCriteria(NamespaceXmlContentDescriberSupport.java:45)
at org.fusesource.ide.foundation.core.xml.namespace.NamespaceXmlContentDescriberSupport.describe(NamespaceXmlContentDescriberSupport.java:77)
at org.fusesource.ide.foundation.core.xml.namespace.NamespaceXmlContentDescriberSupport.describe(NamespaceXmlContentDescriberSupport.java:64)
at org.fusesource.ide.camel.model.service.core.util.CamelFilesFinder.isFuseCamelContentType(CamelFilesFinder.java:112)
at org.fusesource.ide.camel.model.service.core.util.CamelFilesFinder.findFiles(CamelFilesFinder.java:64)
at org.fusesource.ide.camel.model.service.core.util.CamelFilesFinder.findFiles(CamelFilesFinder.java:59)
at org.fusesource.ide.projecttemplates.maven.CamelProjectConfigurator.checkCamelContextsExist(CamelProjectConfigurator.java:333)
at org.fusesource.ide.projecttemplates.maven.CamelProjectConfigurator.configure(CamelProjectConfigurator.java:89)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:122)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$2(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:511)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:505)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:443)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$1(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:358)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1370)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:357)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)*

Comment: Do you have a more complete stack trace from your Error Log?

Comment: I added the stacktrace.